# how to apply css ::before last word

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Is there any possibilities to apply different background colour for **::before** last word
eg : `

```html
<style>
.test::before{
  content : 'stack overflow';
  color: red;
}
</style>
<p class="test"></p>
```

`
In this above mentioned example, I want add different colour for "overflow" text,
any idea ?

Comment: No there is not. Use `before` AND `after` and align as needed.

Answer (score 0):

To render the output you want to visualize, this could be a way:

```css
.test::before {
  content: 'stack';
}
.test::after {
  content: ' overflow';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="test"></p>
```

But It's not appropriate. If your content is just decorative, why don't you put it into a `<span>`?